# Calling custom JavaScript plugin from Angular2

Tags: angular

We have an existing plugin that we call like this

```
var result = $('.myElement').OurPluginName({});
```

I am trying to replace this with a Angular2 Directive.

My **test.ts**:

```
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />
import { Directive, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'test'
})

export class Test {
    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            this.OurPluginName({});
        });
    }
}
```

My **test.d.ts**:

```
declare function OurPluginName(options: Object): void;
```

Despite creating a declaration, it still is giving me an error:

> Property 'OurPluginName' does not exist on type 'Test'.

**SOLUTION:** (thanks to Volodymyr Bilyachat)

**test.ts**:

```
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />
import { Directive, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'test'
})

export class Test {
    public constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
    } 

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            $(this.elRef.nativeElement).OurPluginName({});
        });
    }
}
```

**test.d.ts**:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `this.OurPluginName({})` which is not defined.

```
export class Test {
    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            this.OurPluginName({}); <-- here you call for this
        });
    }
}
```

you should have something like this:

add type definition for $ since your plugin is jquery one

```
declare var $: any;
```

define in class method to call

```
export class Test {
  constructor() {

  }

  CallOurPluginName(options) {
    $('.myElement').OurPluginName({})
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.CallOurPluginName({});
    });
  }
}
```

PS. Its not the best way but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Volodymir. But I was tyring to get rid of the jQuery selector and change it to a directive, so I now have <test></test>. Is it possible?

Comment: @Aximili well but you plugin is jquery plugin?

Comment: @Aximili its possible but you need to rewrite your plugin to be angular component. because var result = $('.myElement').OurPluginName({}); this telling me that you are using jquery

Comment: Sorry it takes an element, doesn't have to be jQuery. It can be $('.myElement')[0].OurPluginName({});

Comment: @Aximili i am lost. If you want just call this function then instead of this call  OurPluginName({}) in your typescript, because current problem is that you try to call function from type Test and this function is not defined

Comment: Sorry I was wrong please ignore my last comment, I got confused myself. You're right. Thank you Volodymyr!

Comment: @Aximili its ok, most important is if you know what to do now?:)

Comment: Yup, to look at how to call the plugin without jQuery ^^;